# Not able to give inputs to a function java.

Tags: java

In this example, i want to add the contents of the two arrays, but I am not able to get how should the input be given. For example, in this case, "invalid assignment operator" error is showing up, for the line int[] a = new int[1,2]. I want to know how to call the function addarr, using the arrays a and b.

public class arradd {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[] a = new int[1,2];
    int[] b = new int[3,4];
    new arradd.addarr(a,b);
}

public void addarr(int[] arr1, int[] arr2){
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
        total += arr1[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++){
        total += arr2[i];
    }
    System.out.println(total);
}
```

}

Comment: It's `new int[]{1,2}`, i.e. the problem is _not_ passing the arrays to the method but the array initialization itself - which probably is mentioned in the error.

Comment: `int[] a = new int[1,2];` that's not how you declare array in Java

Comment: Also `new arradd.addarr(a,b)` would need parentheses after the class name.

Answer (score 1):

One of your problems why the "invalid assignment operator" error is showing up is because you can't do this in java

```
int[] a =new int[1,2];    // will give you a compiler error.
```

the parameter inside the square bracket actually means the size of the array.

```
int[] a=new int[2];
```

here 2 means the size of the array 'a'.

if you want to declare the contents for the array, do this

```
 int[] a=new int[2]{1,2};
```

this is exactly what you need ...where the value inside the square bracket tells the compiler the size of the array 'a' and the values inside the curly braces tells the contents what those are the two contents of the given array 'a'.

And you dont need new operator to or the class name itself to call a method within the class. Just do a

```
addarr(a,b);
```

to call the function and your function would be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring your arrays properly, try this way:

```
int[] a = new int[]{1, 2};
int[] b = new int[]{3,4};
```