# how to use int[] in android java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

first i'm sorry ,i'm a newbie at this,so i confuse about java lang..

if i have a function like this..

```
public static void sendRcOverrideMsg(drone, int[] rcOutputs) {
    msg_rc_channels_override msg = new msg_rc_channels_override();
    msg.chan1_raw = (short) rcOutputs[0];
    msg.chan2_raw = (short) rcOutputs[1];
    msg.chan3_raw = (short) rcOutputs[2];
    msg.chan4_raw = (short) rcOutputs[3];
    msg.chan5_raw = (short) rcOutputs[4];
    msg.chan6_raw = (short) rcOutputs[5];
    msg.chan7_raw = (short) rcOutputs[6];
    msg.chan8_raw = (short) rcOutputs[7];
    msg.target_system = drone.getSysid();
    msg.target_component = drone.getCompid();
    drone.getMavClient().sendMessage(msg, null);
}
```

how can i call that function..
i already call like this :

sendRCOverrideMsg(drone, "//what should i fill in this int[]").. sry before, thanks, hopefully somebody can helm me at this.

Comment: You need to call it with an `int` array of size 8 at least.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to give inputs to a function java.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094829/not-able-to-give-inputs-to-a-function-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[] outputs = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
sendRcOverrideMsg(drone, outputs);
```

Comment: no that should be `int[] outputs = new int[]{8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};`

Comment: thanks all :D, its work